# Using Transfer for on-premises option to transfer files

Tags: docker, file-transfer, agent, google-cloud-data-transfer

[google-cloud-storage]I am trying to copy files from Linux directory to GCP bucket using "Transfer for on-premises" option. I’ve installed docker script on Linux and GCP bucket is created. I now need to run Docker Run command to copy files. My question is how do I specify the source & target places in the docker command. For example; 
Sudo docker run –source  –target  --hostname=$(hostname) --agent-id-prefix=ID123456789

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't supply a source/destination to this command, because its purpose is not to transfer the data. This command starts the agents for the service - agents are always-running processes that help you move data.

After starting agents that have access to your files, you issue a copy command in the Cloud Console, where you can specify a source directory and target bucket+prefix. When you do this, the service will contact the agents and use them to push the data to Google Cloud in parallel, for faster transfers. See the following links for more details:

- [Overview of how Transfer Service for on-premises data works](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/on-prem-overview#how_does_it_work)
- [Setting up the service, and how to submit a transfer job](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/managing-on-prem-jobs)